# Should I use a byte array to send a message of a specific format containing different pieces of information?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program that will be converting information from an xml like file/string (but has no nesting and is almost always the same order unless something goes wrong) into a message to be sent t, will not contain routing information (so not a datagram), and will use sockets.

The message will have different kinds of data, containing 32 bit unsigned ints, 32 bit reals, 64 bit reals, 64 bit unsigned ints, and 16 bit unsigned ints.  The first 16 bytes of the message serve as the header (similar to a datagram, but without routing information), and will contain information such as message type and message size.

The message will contain data on atleast 10 observations and parameters to use in what ever decisions to make using data.

I originally was going to send the message as a datagram until I realized that the message would not have any routing information.

The system uses point to point communication, and both elements know where to send their data.

Since this is not a datagram, and the message has a maximum size of 1888 bytes size, with different bytes containing different information, should I use a byte array to store and send the different pieces of data in one message?

EDIT:  Here is a sample of what the message structure is like.

Bytes 0 to 15  : Message header containing Message type(bytes 4-7) and message size(12-15) and other stuff, all 32 bit unsigned ints, except for bytes 8 to 11(reserved for unused).

Bytes 24 to 25 : Chunk number , usigned 16 bit integer.

Bytes 128-131 :  Point of Origin Data relative to system, Real 32

Also, just to further clarify, this is using Java to send a message from a radar computer to another computer.

Comment: This question belongs on a different stackexchange site. White-board type questions are off-topic for SO

Comment: Unclear. Include the relevant code. If you use sockets, then you can send in whatever format, even the xml itself theoretically (though not very efficient)

Comment: You could use a [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), which abstract sending and receiving of byte arrays into useful primitive types.

Comment: @Vulcan could you explain what that would look like?  Would I be using byte arrays then?

Comment: To transmit a message containing an int, a byte, and a string (in that order) you would do `out.writeInt(x); out.writeByte(y); out.writeUTF(z);` and then to read them, you would do `x = in.readInt(); y = in.readByte(); z = in.readUTF()`. (Sorry for the one-line code formatting)

Comment: @Vulcan Can you expand upon it as an answer? The code will look better too.

Comment: @cluemein I'm not completely sure I understand your data format so I don't want to write a misleading answer, and I'm not sure how I'd further expand that brief example. [Here's an example](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/essential/io/dataIO.html) usage that might help you better understand these streams. Basically, I could see you using my previous example code in a way where you first write (and later first read) bytes 0-3 to whatever they are (`read/writeInt`), then bytes 4-7 (another `read/writeInt`) and so forth.

Comment: The DataOutputStream comment and out.writeInt(x) comment actually proved very useful, but not in this part of the project.  Voted them up though since they helped me in a related task though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was approaching this as if it was C or C++ lol.  My syntax wasn't wrong, but I was making things a lot harder than they needed to be.

Ultimately I came up with the idea of using a builder pattern to mash the contents of two classes together, both classes containing an array of objects of predetermined byte size(float(32 bit real), long(64 bit int), double(64 bit real), int(32 bit int), short(16 bit int)). I followed this example and expanded on it:

[image]

In my case, Burger and ColdDrink were replaced with PayloadData and HeaderData respectively, and also added some smaller patterns onto it.  Item was replaced with MessageElement, and had int elementSize(), which PayloadData and HeaderData override.  PayloadData is in turn overrode by the different kind of message (the header structure and construction method never changes, so that isn't overrode).  Thanks for suggestions in the comments though, they also gave me some ideas.